# create a localized site column

Tags: 2007, localization

How to create a localized column field?

For example, when using sharepoint in French, the field "Name" automatically gets translated to "Nom".

i want to create a column that automatically changes its display according to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the site column, change the language to something else, than edit the column name and update it with the corresponding value. that's it, sharepoint will automatically show the column in the appropriate language.(there is a configuration in site settings --> site administration-->language settings where you specify to overwrite translations with users translations.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `\12\TEMPLATE\XML\FLDTYPES.XML` file to see how it is implemented for built-in SharePoint fields.

Example:

```
<FieldType>
  <Field Name="TypeName">AllDayEvent</Field>
  <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">$Resources:core,All_Day_Event;</Field>
  <Field Name="InternalType">AllDayEvent</Field>
```

Comment: CAn you give more details please?

Comment: @Zee99 What have you achieved so far? Have you created a non-localized column field? Can you post any code? Basically, what you have to do is: (1) create a resource files for languages you need, (2) deploy them to appropriate folders, (3) set value of `TypeDisplayName` using the `$Resources:resource_file_name,key_name_from_the_file;` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I in a search for the an answer on the same question I found this article that may help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955226.aspx